# Unable to get BFS algorithm to work properly in c++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a dungeon/rouge-like game in c++ and am trying to implement pathfinding.

The issue I am having is that when the player moves more than two times the adjacency matrix doesn't generate properly. What happens is that every place that the player has been turning to a zero which signifies that you cant go there. I am trying to regenerate the matrix every time the player moves but it doesn't seem to want to. here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int World_Width = 10;
    int World_Height = 10;

    int Player_X = 1;
    int Player_Y = 2;

    int Enemy_X = 8;
    int Enemy_Y = 1;

    int X = Player_X;
    int Y = Player_Y;

    int Player_Health = 10;
    int Enemy_Health = 5;

    int Player_Damage = 1;
    int Enemy_Damage = 1;

    bool PlayerIsAlive = true;
    bool EnemyIsAlive = true;

    int World[World_Width][World_Height] =
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1},
        {1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    };
    int NodeMap[World_Width][World_Height] =
    {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    };

    int NeighborMap[World_Width][World_Height] =
    {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,},
    };

    int NodeNumber = 1;
    for (int h = 0; h < World_Height; h++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < World_Width; d++)
        {
            NodeMap[h][d] = NodeNumber;
            NodeNumber ++;
        }
    }


    vector<int> queue {};
    vector<int> visited {};

    string input;

    bool AddNode = true;
    int QueueNumber = 0;

    int Max_iterations = 1000;

    int TurnCount = 0;
    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        TurnCount += 1;
        //Prints out the map
        for (int h = 0; h < World_Height; h++)
        {
            for (int d = 0; d < World_Width; d++)
            {
                cout << World[h][d] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Player health: " << Player_Health << "\n";
        cout << "Enemy health: " << Enemy_Health << "\n" << "\n";


        cout << "What do you want to do; move, attack, or open a chest: ";

        //Player movement
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "w"  && World[Player_Y - 1][Player_X] == 0)
        {
            World[Player_Y ][Player_X] = 0;

            Player_Y--;
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 2;
        }

        if (input == "a" && World[Player_Y][Player_X - 1] == 0)
        {
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 0;

            Player_X--;
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 2;
        }

        if (input == "s"  && World[Player_Y + 1][Player_X] == 0)
        {
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 0;

            Player_Y++;
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 2;
        }

        if (input == "d" && World[Player_Y][Player_X + 1] == 0)
        {
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 0;

            Player_X++;
            World[Player_Y][Player_X] = 2;
        }
        if (input == "e")
        {
            if (Player_X == Enemy_X && Player_Y - 1 == Enemy_Y)
            {
                Enemy_Health -= Player_Damage;
            }
            if (Player_X == Enemy_X - 1 && Player_Y == Enemy_Y)
            {
                Enemy_Health -= Player_Damage;
            }
            if (Player_X == Enemy_X && Player_Y + 1 == Enemy_Y)
            {
                Enemy_Health -= Player_Damage;
            }
            if (Player_X == Enemy_X + 1 && Player_Y == Enemy_Y)
            {
                Enemy_Health -= Player_Damage;
            }
        }
        if ( input == "stop")
        {
            Player_Health = 0;
        }

        queue.clear();
        QueueNumber = 0;
        X = Player_X;
        Y = Player_Y;
        NeighborMap[Y][X] = 0;
        //BFS - Breadth First Search: Pathfinding Algorithim
        for (int iterations = 0; iterations < Max_iterations; iterations++)
        {

            if (World[Y - 1][X] == 0 || World[Y - 1][X] == 4)
            {
                AddNode = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i] == NodeMap[Y - 1][X])
                    {
                        AddNode = false;
                    }
                }
                if (AddNode)
                {
                    queue.push_back(NodeMap[Y - 1][X]);
                    NeighborMap[Y - 1][X] = NodeMap[Y][X];
                }
            }
            if (World[Y][X - 1] == 0 || World[Y][X - 1] == 4)
            {
                AddNode = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i] == NodeMap[Y][X - 1])
                    {
                        AddNode = false;
                    }
                }
                if (AddNode)
                {
                    queue.push_back(NodeMap[Y][X - 1]);
                    NeighborMap[Y][X - 1] = NodeMap[Y][X];
                }
            }
            if (World[Y + 1][X] == 0 || World[Y + 1][X] == 4)
            {
                AddNode = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i] == NodeMap[Y + 1][X])
                    {
                        AddNode = false;
                    }
                }
                if (AddNode)
                {
                    queue.push_back(NodeMap[Y + 1][X]);
                    NeighborMap[Y + 1][X] = NodeMap[Y][X];
                }
            }
            if (World[Y][X + 1] == 0 || World[Y][X + 1] == 4)
            {
                AddNode = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (visited[i] == NodeMap[Y][X + 1])
                    {
                        AddNode = false;
                    }
                }
                if (AddNode)
                {
                    queue.push_back(NodeMap[Y][X + 1]);
                    NeighborMap[Y][X + 1] = NodeMap[Y][X];
                }
            }
            for (int h = 0; h < World_Height; h++)
            {
                for (int d = 0; d < World_Width; d++)
                {
                    if(NodeMap[h][d] == queue[QueueNumber])
                    {
                        X = d;
                        Y = h;
                    }
                }
            }
            visited.push_back(queue[QueueNumber]);
            QueueNumber++;
        }

        //Enemy AI
        if (Enemy_Health == 0)
        {
            if (EnemyIsAlive)
            {
                World[Enemy_Y][Enemy_X] = 0;
            }
            EnemyIsAlive = false;
        }


        if (Player_Health == 0)
        {
            run = false;
        }
    }
    system("clear");
    for (int h = 0; h < World_Height; h++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < World_Width; d++)
        {
            cout << NeighborMap[h][d] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int h = 0; h < World_Height; h++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < World_Width; d++)
        {
            cout << NodeMap[h][d] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "GAME OVER" << "\n" << "Thanks for Playing!";
}
```

Comment: Notable: "bugs out" - the literal definition of why *debuggers* were invented.

Comment: If you compile your program with a address sanitizer, it shows you the line where the bug appears. Compile your program with `-fsanitize=address`(gcc, clang) or `/fsanitize=address`(msvc)

Comment: sorry saying it bugs out isn't correct. it doesn't give me any errors it just doesn't generate the adjacency matrix correctly and I have no clue why.

Comment: @HashDankHog That was just a playful way of telling you to try to get used to using your debugger. With the debugger you can step through the program bit by bit and see the contents of memory at each step, which can help you identify where the mistake is.

Comment: Why you put everything in `main`? This make this code unreadable.